# Deleting repositories on GitHub

Tags: github

Can someone please help me delete a repository I have created as a test repository on GitHub. I am using the Android FastHub application.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The simplest method is to log into your account and delete it through the browser.  However, questions about Android devices, are not within scope here at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Open the repository on GitHub through a web browser, and if you're on a mobile browser, be sure to switch to "desktop" mode (either through Chrome's "Request a desktop site" menu option, or through GitHub's own link in the page footer).

Repository deletion is under *Settings*, at the very bottom of the first "Options" page (the so-labelled 'Danger Zone').